# SQL Server Compact Toolbox Won't Install with VS 2015

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-toolbox

I download SqlCeToolbox.4.4.0.4.vsix and when I double clicked on it, nothing happened. So I put it in the %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extnesions folder and it still won't work.

I searched around, but couldn't find anything. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.telerik.com/forums/visual-studio-extension-is-not-installing-on-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-windows-10-enterprise) finally worked for me.

1. Open a CMD window as Administrator
2. Go to Common, IDE folder of the VS 2015 installation. In my case:

   ```
   CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
   ```
3. Execute the installer passing the VSIX file as parameter. In my case:

   ```
   VSIXInstaller.exe c:\AppBuilder.vsix
   ```